# Starling Android Dev: Black screen after phone call on galaxy note 2

Tags: android, flash, air, starling-framework

I'm testing my starling game on galaxy note 2. Starling turns into black screen after phone calls... The strange thing is that it works on other android devices(HTC,sony，etc.).

I did set

```
Starling.handleLostContext = true.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you tried to ask at starling forum?

Comment: This is not just a problem with your game. My Note 2 goes to a black screen after a call when using Sygic Aura or even just in phone mode. Real nuisance when using Sygic as it is SatNav program! Hoipe someone can help with this as it is a real pain!

Comment: It sounds like you are loosing context. IS there anything in the log. Can you debug my theory?